# Combining clsact and classful qdiscs together

Tags: ebpf, trafficshaping

I need to work with `clsact` qdisc and ebpf filter on it but at the same time I want to shape my traffic using e.g. `htb` qdisc.
While `clsact` acts as a root qdisc I can't attach it as a leaf of any of `htb` classes. At the same time `clsact` is classless qdisc and I can't attach any qdisc underneath it.

ebpf program working as filter with `direct-action` (`da`) flag can return `classid` in `skb->tc_classid` and I would like to use it to choose a right class (what class if `clsact` is classless?).